# How to awk only in a certain row and specific column

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sh

For example i have the following file:

```
4:Oscar:Ferk:Florida
14:Steven:Pain:Texas
7:Maya:Ross:California
```

and so on... 
It has an unknown number of lines because you can keep adding more to it.
I'm writing a script where you can edit the name by giving in the id of the person and the new name you want to give it as parameters.

What i am trying to do is use awk to find the line and then change the name on that specific line and update the file. I'm having trouble because my code updates every single column value to the given one.

My current code is:

```
getID=$1
getName=$2

awk -v varID="$getID" -F':' '$0~varID' file.dat | awk -v varName="$getName" -F':' '$2=varName' file.dat > tmp && mv tmp file.dat
```

Help is really appreciated, thank you kindly in advance.

Comment: Hint *if* you want to understand what you are doing wrong: Run only `awk -v varName="AA" -F':' '$2=varName' file.dat`. *Else*, just use an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this awk:

```
getID=14          # change to getID="$1"
getName='John K'  # change to getName="$2"

awk -v id="$getID" -v name="$getName" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} $1==id{$2=name} 1' file
```

```
4:Oscar:Ferk:Florida
14:John K:Pain:Texas
7:Maya:Ross:California
```